Login and terminal lags in Ubuntu 22.04
So today, after updating and installing a few additional apt packages that katrain requires, I started having the following two (possibly unrelated) never before experienced problems:

When logging in to gnome (x11), after filling in pass and pressing enter, it takes longer than usual and when the desktop shows, it is frozen: I can move the mouse cursor but not interact with anything. Then after a while, the screen turns black again and a mouse cursor turns up on the black screen and then the desktop turns up again, now working as expected.

The input in gnome terminal lags, i.e. when I write abc... the c or both bc would show well after pressing (it's not consistent, just every other character or so, but enough to be really annoying). It behaves as in this unanswered question.


Question: Does anyone have any idea how this would start happening now, and not before, and what it may relate to? (graphics obviously).
Additional info

The freeze only happens on the first login after reboot, not when logging out and in.
The only thing I did before the problem appeared was to sudo update and upgrade and installing the following katrain dependencies:

sudo apt install python3-pip build-essential git python3 python3-dev ffmpeg libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev\
    libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev zlib1g-dev\
    libgstreamer1.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good libpulse\
    pkg-config libgl-dev opencl-headers ocl-icd-opencl-dev libzip-dev

of which most was already installed. But, I don't know how to figure out which ones was already installed and not, so I don't know which to try and remove.
System info
i9-14900K
64mb ddr5
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 4060
GPU Driver Version: 535.171.04
Ubuntu 22.04
Kernel: 6.5.0-27-generic
Display server: x11


I've been having the same issue. Another issue I have is Chrome freezing during downloads. I'm not sure if they're related. I also have an NVIDIA GPU (RTX 3090).

I have exactly the same problem, laptop RTX 3080, happens on fresh 24.04 beta installation. It's brutal and practically unusable for long periods.

The only fix I have been able to find is to get Wayland working.

Does this answer your question? input delay on Terminal Ubuntu 22.04.4
